# How to drop a dataframe column with the subset function and a variable?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with a bunch of columns. I'd like to drop one of the columns named **age**..

```
type.name <- "age"
```

so I tried

```
df <- subset(df, select = -type.name)
```

but it throws the error: *invalid argument to unary operator*.

However, this does work

```
df <- subset(df, select = -age)
```

How do I do get it to work dynamically with the variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works with

```
subset(df, select = -eval(parse(text=type.name)))
```

and

```
subset(df, select = names(df) != type.name)
```

and

```
"[[<-"(df, type.name, value = NULL)
```

Comment: Don't forget the time-honored `df$age <- NULL`!